# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found in python

Tags: python, nltk

I want to stem the words, for which i import the `porterstemmer` pkg from `nltk` but an error occurred at run time.

The error is :

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

My Python code is

```
  import nltk;     
  from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer  
  stemmer=PorterStemmer()  
  file = open('C:/Python26/test.txt','r')  
  f=open("root.txt",'w')  
  with open(file,'r',-1) as rf:  
    lines = rf.readlines()  
    for word in lines:  
        root = stemmer.stem(word)  
        f.write(root+"\n")  
    f.close()
```

yes i tried it and got an error which i couldn't understand ad the error was                                                                                                             1.6.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\check.py", line 10, in 
    with open(file,'r',-1) as rf:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

> > > ```
> > >                                                                                                     My code after ur recommended change is 
> > > import nltk;
> > > import numpy;
> > > import numpy as np
> > > from StringIO import StringIO
> > > print numpy.__version__
> > > from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer  
> > > stemmer=PorterStemmer()  
> > > file = np.genfromtxt('C:/Python26/test.txt', delimiter=" ")  
> > > f=open("root.txt",'w')  
> > > with open(file,'r',-1) as rf:
> > >     lines = rf.readlines()  
> > >     for word in lines:  
> > >         root = stemmer.stem(word)  
> > >         f.write(root+"\n")  
> > >     f.close()                                                                                                         and my dummy file is like this
> > > ```
> > >
> > > walking
> > >       talked
> > >       oranges
> > >       books
> > >       Src
> > >       Src
> > >       mAB

Answer (score 2):

You have already opened the file. You're trying to pass a file object to `with open...`. Remove `file = open('C:/...` line.

P.S. 
You will be iterating over lines, not words.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening `file` in line 4 and then use that as the filename for another `open()` in line 6. Just do:

```
import nltk;     
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer  
stemmer=PorterStemmer()  
with open("root.txt",'w') as f:
    with open('C:/Python26/test.txt','r',-1) as rf:  
      lines = rf.readlines()  
      for word in lines:  
          root = stemmer.stem(word)  
          f.write(root+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is with the parameters passed to a function, and i'm guessing its in the line `root = stemmer.stem(word)`

try using the function genfromtxt instead of open():

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> np.genfromtxt('C:/Python26/test.txt', delimiter=",") #Whatever delimiter your file has.
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: I tried the code of "Anthon"  it did not create any error but did not stem the word

Comment: @ShaheenGul did you try mine?

Comment: yes i tried it and got an error which i couldn't understand ad the error was

Comment: have you declares coding at the start of your document? put this at the start of your file and see if the error persists  `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`

Comment: What this mean?? I can't understand, anyhow i also do this but same result when i add # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- – , as # is used for commenting the text, but when i remove this then error was encountered

Comment: sometimes it is an option to search a little before asking `# -- coding: UTF-8 --` sets the encoding so that it accepts characters  different than those in [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) form by setting the default coding to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which contains a more extensive list of characters to be taken into account, so you must set the encoding in a way the program is able to understand your input if your input requires it (by setting it with the expression i showed you or this `source = unicode(source, 'utf-8')`). and I know this is at least part of

Comment: the issue because pythons default coding is ASCII